# Cannot use legacy GL library with cmake (ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04)

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, cmake

I have a very simple CMakeLists.txt, where I use OpenGL and I need to link with legacy OpenGL.
Policy [CMP0072](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/policy/CMP0072.html) says that I need to set `OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE` to `LEGACY`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Foo)

set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE LEGACY)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp)

add_executable(foo
    ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(
    foo
    PUBLIC OpenGL::GLU
    )
```

However, cmake output is:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alessandro/tmp/foo/build
```

It is linking `libOpenGL.so` instead of `libGL.so`.

Moreover, if I comment the line `set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE LEGACY)`, I get the following output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:275 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so   
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alessandro/tmp/foo/build
```

which is quite confusing: it first says that prefers to use `GLVND` by default, but then

> for compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.

In any case, both `libGL.so` and `libOpenGL.so` are installed, and `libOpenGL.so` is set.

I cannot figure out where could be the issue, and how can I force cmake to use legacy GL instead of GLVND.

Running ubuntu 20.04, but the behaviour is the same also in ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It seems that the first variant should work, but CMake output in that case is confusing: CMake has found **both** flows of OpenGL, but the first instance was `OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY`, so it is printed in `-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so`. You should be able to use variable `OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY` or target `OpenGL::GL` for access legacy OpenGL.

Comment: Probably, replacing `list(APPEND _OpenGL_REQUIRED_VARS OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY)` with `list(PREPEND _OpenGL_REQUIRED_VARS OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY)` in [FindOpenGL.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake#L380) should fix that confusing output.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. So, if I understood correctly, there are two targets: `OpenGL::GL` and `OpenGL::OpenGL`. Therefore `OpenGL::OpenGL` is GLVND anyway and `OpenGL::GL` could be legacy or GLVND depending on the policy? And the `Found OpenGL:` print it is not related with these two targets? This is very confusing, and also not-well documented..

Comment: Targets ``OpenGL::OpenGL`` and `OpenGL::GL` are described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenGL.html). As for content of `Found XXX: ...` output, I have seen no modules (neither modules shipped with CMake nor externals ones) which document that output.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `CMakeLists.txt`  file.

```
set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE LEGACY)
```

Comment: This is already present in the question, along with some more details.